# C# Async WebRequests: Perform Action When All Requests Are Completed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webrequest, waithandle

I have this basic scraping console application in C# that Asynchronously uses WebRequest to get html from a list of sites. It works fine, but how do I set up a trigger that goes off when every site in the list has been processed?

I've spent a couple hours researching various solutions online, including the MS docs, but none of them provide a straight forward answer via code. I've read about the IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle but I have no clue how to integrate it into my code. I'd just like to call a custom function when all threads complete processing or timeout.

One trick is that I never know ahead of time how many sites are in my list (it's user defined), so I need a solution that's robust enough to wait for 5 events for 100,000 events to complete.

Thanks. Working code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;


namespace AsyncApp_01
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList alSites = new ArrayList();
            alSites.Add("http://www.google.com");
            alSites.Add("http://www.lostspires.com");

            ScanSites(alSites);

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void ScanSites(ArrayList sites)
        {
            foreach (string uriString in sites)
            {
                WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uriString);
                request.Method = "GET";
                object data = new object(); //container for our "Stuff"

                // RequestState is a custom class to pass info to the callback
                RequestState state = new RequestState(request, data, uriString);
                IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(UpdateItem), state);


                //Register the timeout callback
                ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(result.AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(ScanTimeoutCallback), state, (30 * 1000), true);

            }
        }


        private static void UpdateItem(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            // grab the custom state object
            RequestState state = (RequestState)result.AsyncState;
            WebRequest request = (WebRequest)state.Request;

            // get the Response
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
            Stream s = (Stream)response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(s);

            // dataString will hold the entire contents of the requested page if we need it.
            string dataString = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
            s.Close();
            readStream.Close();

            Console.WriteLine(dataString);
        }


        private static void ScanTimeoutCallback(object state, bool timedOut)
        {
            if (timedOut)
            {
                RequestState reqState = (RequestState)state;
                if (reqState != null)
                {
                    reqState.Request.Abort();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("aborted- timeout");
            }
        } 


        class RequestState
        {
            public WebRequest Request; // holds the request
            public object Data; // store any data in this
            public string SiteUrl; // holds the UrlString to match up results (Database lookup, etc).

            public RequestState(WebRequest request, object data, string siteUrl)
            {
                this.Request = request;
                this.Data = data;
                this.SiteUrl = siteUrl;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Bonus points for anyone who can also tell me how to limit the number of concurrent threads. For example, if I have 100 sites to process, how do I set it up so that 10 sites get processed at a time, but not more. I don't want to open 100 threads.

Comment: Seems like I completely ignored the part about reading the stream asynchronously. My apologies. See MSDN for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wf6409%28v=vs.71%29.aspx It complicates things considerably, but you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: So... is Interlocked.Increment(ref _count); still to be use? Cause I've noticed it gives me incorrect counts from time to time. Also, I need to implement a timeout with ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick sample I threw together. I removed the WebClient implementation, as it seems like you're using the WebRequest one. I'm also making use of .Net 4's ConcurrentBag:

```
public class Scraper
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> _sites;
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<string> _data;
    private volatile int _count;
    private readonly int _total;
    public Scraper(IEnumerable<string> sites)
    {
        _sites = sites;
        _data = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
        _total = sites.Count();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        foreach (var site in _sites)
        {
            ScrapeSite(site);
        }
    }

    private void ScrapeSite(string site)
    {
        var req = WebRequest.Create(site);
        req.BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback, req);
    }

    private void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
        var req = ar.AsyncState as WebRequest;

        var result = req.EndGetResponse(ar);
        var reader = new StreamReader(result.GetResponseStream());
        var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        this.OnSiteScraped(req.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri, data);
        _data.Add(data);
        if (_count == _total)
        {
            OnScrapingComplete();
        }
    }

    private void OnSiteScraped(string site, string data)
    {
        var handler = this.SiteScraped;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new SiteScrapedEventArgs(site, data));
        }
    }

    private void OnScrapingComplete()
    {
        var handler = this.ScrapingComplete;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new ScrapingCompletedEventArgs(_data));
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<SiteScrapedEventArgs> SiteScraped;
    public event EventHandler<ScrapingCompletedEventArgs> ScrapingComplete;
}

public class SiteScrapedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Site { get; private set; }
    public string Data { get; private set; }
    public SiteScrapedEventArgs(string site, string data)
    {
        this.Site = site;
        this.Data = data;
    }
}
```

OK, I created some basic classes, and this should do the trick. If this isn't enough, I'm sorry, I simply can't help you:

```
 public class RankedPage
    {
        public int Rank { get; set; }
        public string Site { get; set; }
    }

    public class WebRequestData
    {
        public WebRequest WebRequest { get; set; }
        public RankedPage Page { get; set; }
    }

    public class Scraper
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<RankedPage> _sites;
        private readonly ConcurrentBag<KeyValuePair<RankedPage,string>> _data;
        private volatile int _count;
        private readonly int _total;
        public Scraper(IEnumerable<RankedPage> sites)
        {
            _sites = sites;
            _data = new ConcurrentBag<KeyValuePair<RankedPage, string>>();
            _total = sites.Count();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            foreach (var site in _sites)
            {
                ScrapeSite(site);
            }
        }

        private void ScrapeSite(RankedPage site)
        {
            var req = WebRequest.Create(site.Site);
            req.BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback, new WebRequestData{ Page = site, WebRequest = req});
        }

        private void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
            var webRequestData = ar.AsyncState as WebRequestData;

            var req = webRequestData.WebRequest;
            var result = req.EndGetResponse(ar);
            var reader = new StreamReader(result.GetResponseStream());
            var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            this.OnSiteScraped(webRequestData.Page, data);
            _data.Add(new KeyValuePair<RankedPage, string>(webRequestData.Page,data));
            if (_count == _total)
            {
                OnScrapingComplete();
            }
        }

        private void OnSiteScraped(RankedPage page, string data)
        {
            var handler = this.SiteScraped;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new SiteScrapedEventArgs(page, data));
            }
        }

        private void OnScrapingComplete()
        {
            var handler = this.ScrapingComplete;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new ScrapingCompletedEventArgs(_data));
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler<SiteScrapedEventArgs> SiteScraped;
        public event EventHandler<ScrapingCompletedEventArgs> ScrapingComplete;
    }

    public class SiteScrapedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public RankedPage Site { get; private set; }
        public string Data { get; private set; }
        public SiteScrapedEventArgs(RankedPage site, string data)
        {
            this.Site = site;
            this.Data = data;
        }
    }

    public class ScrapingCompletedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<RankedPage,string >> SiteData { get; private set; }
        public ScrapingCompletedEventArgs(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<RankedPage, string>> siteData)
        {
            this.SiteData = siteData;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @BFree: I'm grateful for the help, but your code is completely different from mine, even in the second case. I'm relying on static functions throughout my code, I'm not familiar with ConcurrentBag,  and I don't understand how your code handles timeouts. I've tried to use your code but feel even more lost.

Comment: I am trying. What I don't understand at the moment is how to convert my ArrayList of URLs into the IEnumerable<string>.

Comment: Trying to cast, but it's not working: Scraper myScraper = new Scraper((IEnumerable<string>)alSites);

Comment: Got the cast to work so the app is running through the list of URLs, but the ultimate goal still eludes me: nothing triggers when all threads are complete. I placed a Console.WriteLine in the OnScrapingComplete function, but it never fires.

Comment: @user77282: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I thought you wanted an event to fire when they're ALL done. I just updated my code to fire an event when each one is done. I also removed the WebClient version, as it seems you're using the WebReqeust.

Comment: Okay, I got the trigger firing on completion of all threads (that's what I wanted). The issue now is that I need to access the site URL that was used to each particular WebRequest inside the AsyncCallback, so I can pair up URLs with their html and other data. Is there any way to get "site" inside of AsyncCallback?

Comment: @user772282: See my latest edit. Now every time a site is complete, it fires an event that passes both the site and the html in the event. You can also update the event that fires when all are complete to pass a dictionary that's site => html. If you don't know how do to that, let me know, and I'll update...

Comment: I need to pass along data with each scrape: I start off with a list of URLs and their corresponding PageRank values. After scraping each URL's html, I would like to output to a listArray that holds the URL, html, and PageRank of each site in a table-like format. I don't know how to sync the PageRank value back up. That is, I need access to the PageRank in OnSiteScraped() somehow.

Comment: @user772282: The second parameter of BeginGetResponse is object. When I'm calling it from ScrapeSite I'm just using it to pass the WebRequest itself. What you can do is, create a custom class that combines the WebRequest object, the URL, PageRank etc. Then, in the callback, cast the ar.AsyncState to that type of object, and you have everything you need.

Comment: Sounds great... and also complicated. Can you show an example please? I think this is last bit I need to get everything working properly.

Comment: I have no idea where you're getting the PageRank data and all that stuff. All I see is you're passing in a list of strings. I can't show you an example without knowing that. Furthermore, what I've outlined isn't complicated at all, and if you really can't figure it out, then maybe you need to hit up some OO tutorials first. Not trying to be a d*ck, but it's really not all that hard.

Comment: I don't need a full solution, just don't understand how to pass a string into this custom class and merge it with WebRequest. In all honesty I spent 10 hours today researching every corner of the web to get my original solution, but it fell short. Your solution seems good, but I don't know how to pass a variable through the WebRequest. Each URL simply has a PageRank variable associated with it at the getgo. Imagine there are two ArrayLists at the start, Sites and PR, such that Sites[0] = http://www.google.com and PR[0] = 10, etc.

Comment: Come one man, use your imagination. Instead of passing an IEnumerable<string> to the Scraper, pass some kind of data structure that contains all the data you need per site.

Comment: It's not lack of imagination, it's lack of intimate familiarity with C#'s Async Response methods. That shit take's weeks of head against wall to understand.