# WPF STA thread error

Tags: wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I am following the code given on this thread [C# Async WebRequests: Perform Action When All Requests Are Completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146744/c-sharp-async-webrequests-perform-action-when-all-requests-are-completed)

In my WPF app I need to asynchronously download images from the server. However I get the following error

`The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.`

Could it be because I am doing UI updates on the main thread? I have also declared the calling thread's state to STA, my code follows:

```
    private void FixedDocument_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AsyncLoadImages));
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();
    }

    private void AsyncLoadImages()
    {
        foreach (string resFile in resFiles)
        {
            string imageuri = @"http://www.example.com/image.jpg";
            
            WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(imageuri);
            request.Method = "GET";
            object data = new object();
            RequestState state = new RequestState(request, data);

            IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(
              new AsyncCallback(UpdateItem), state);

            ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(result.AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(ScanTimeoutCallback), state, (30 * 1000), true);
        }
    }

    private static void ScanTimeoutCallback(object state, bool timedOut)
    {
        if (timedOut)
        {
            RequestState reqState = (RequestState)state;
            if (reqState != null)
            {
                reqState.Request.Abort();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("aborted- timeout");
        }
    }

    private void UpdateItem(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        RequestState state = (RequestState)result.AsyncState;
        WebRequest request = (WebRequest)state.Request;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);          
        
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();

        bi.StreamSource = response.GetResponseStream();                        
        bi.EndInit();

        Image i  = new Image(); //hitting the error at this line
    i.Source = bi;  
    }
```

Please can someone help?

Many Thanks

Comment: Also, calling `t.Join()` will block the UI thread

Comment: UpdateItem runs on a threadpool thread, they are always MTA.  But setting the worker thread to STA doesn't help anyway, it is the wrong single threaded apartment.  You will have to use Dispatcher.Begin/Invoke() to create the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call every UI operation in the MainThread i guess your UpdateItem method will not be called in the UI Thread thus you get this exception.

i would change 2 things:

First, use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class, which makes this kind of async operations in WPF alot simpler.

Second, if you have another thread (Backgroundworker or custom Thread) you always must [Dispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591593.aspx) every UI operation into the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can try wrapping your code in below, this however is dirty solution.

```
MyUIElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
{

    //your code here

}));
```

best if MyUIElement was your top window.